# Returning Gson JsonObject in REST Jersey response gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: json, rest, gson, jersey-2.0

I have following method which returns a JsonObject as Rest response :

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response testMethod(){
    String json = "{\"key\" : \"value\"}";
    JsonObject jsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
    return Response.ok().entity(jsonObj).build();
}
```

The response is 500 Internal Server Error.
The same works fine when I put any other object in the 'entity' parameter.

Comment: Just `toString()` it. Otherwise you will need to create a MessageBodyWriter for it

Comment: Just doing toString(), response contains escaped quotes with backslashes.

Comment: I don't use Gson. How would you get the normalized String representation from it (if not toString())? Do _that_.

Comment: Gson's toJson method allows me to do that. However, the string so obtained still contains escaped quotes which is undesirable.

Comment: I don't know then. Probably someone more versed in Gson can help. Seems odd to me that this would be the (normal) behavior.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, for me it works as expected the Response: {"key":"value"}. Which version of Gson you are using?